# Pyramid + ZODB Image storing

Tags: python, pyramid, zodb

I have an upload form that accepts a zip file and has a method that unzips it and get each file from it. Make a unique id from the md5 hash of it and stores them in a dictionary;

```
dict[uid] = imagebinary
```

and returns it so that the form can store them into ZODB. I can't store the image just like that, as this error spits out;

```
    2013-01-31 08:59:59,061 ERROR [waitress][Dummy-5] Exception when serving /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 329, in service
    task.service()
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 173, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 380, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "/home/maverick/.buildout/eggs/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 251, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/maverick/.buildout/eggs/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 227, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 133, in toolbar_tween
    body = tb.render_full(request).encode('utf-8', 'replace')
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/tbtools.py", line 240, in render_full
    summary = self.render_summary(include_title=False, request=request)
  File "/home/maverick/inigo/sources/devenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/tbtools.py", line 229, in render_summary
    'description':  description_wrapper % escape(self.exception),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, how should I go about doing that? I'm pretty much stuck on this.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback. What type is `imagebinary` and what type is `uid`? The ZODB can store *any* default python type, so this is most likely *not* the ZODB.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `uid` is `str` and `imagebinary` is `str` which is read from the zipfile, and I think that's causing the problem?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the ZODB; please do include more context of the code; `'description':  description_wrapper % escape(self.exception),` is failing in the debug toolbar masking the real exception.

Comment: well, I now know why the UnicodeDecodeErrors, I've been stupidly just doing, uid = imagebinary.read(), which is pretty much wrong, right?

So, in general, how do I store the image properly in pyramid+zodb?

I want to be able to call the image at say, root['images'][uid].image, and gets the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you see is unrelated to image storing in the ZODB.

To store larger pieces of data, you really want to use a ZODB `Blob` instead of putting the image data directly in an attribute. `Blob`s are stored separately on disk and do not flush the ZODB cache, and can be streamed back to the client on access again.

To create and store a `Blob`, use:

```
from ZODB.blob import Blob

uid = Blob(imagebinary.read())
```

Once created like that, you can later use `uid` as a file; you need to open it in read or write mode first. To return the contents of the blob from a view, for example, use:

```
from pyramid.response import Response

def serveimage(request):
    # retrieve uid from somewhere
    resp = Response(content_type='image/jpeg')
    resp.app_iter = uid.open('r')  # open for reading
    return resp
```

Blobs are bound to transactions and changes to them are automatically discarded if the transaction is rolled back.